# How to configure dynamic subpath for react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx

I want to deploy my react app with subpath (subdirectory path) but I don't want to set the subdirectory/path name in react app as this subdirectory name may change in future.

How to make configuration at react app level as it can work for any subdirectory name at server side which will not be hardcoded at react app level and it will be as a subpath for the application url.

eg. https://www.dummyname.com/anysubpath

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reusable HOC and handle the logic of the server data in that and pass it to the `path` property in react-router.

For a dynamic path (slug) use dynamic routes like below:

```
<Route path="/some-path/:slug" component={SomeComponent} />
```

For more details refer to [React router dynamic routing](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/philosophy#:%7E:text=When%20we%20say%20dynamic%20routing,a%20component%20in%20React%20Router.)

Comment: But I dont want to add any some-path as hardcoded in the app.

Comment: It's just for example the main part is the `/:slug`, replace the `slug` with  your path

Comment: In my case the *some-path* will be dynamic, that I  cant make hardcoded.

Comment: ok no problem just use the slug

Comment: slug will not work as it will allow to be set different name for slug whenever user open the app in browser.

Comment: what do you mean?